# GraphQL LSP with CoC + Neovim

Tags: javascript, graphql, neovim

I'm trying to setup a GraphQL language server for use within NVIM for linting, through CoC (Conquer of Completion).

I've installed the LSP from GraphQL [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/tree/main/packages/graphql-language-service-cli) but I'm having trouble getting it to recognize my GQL schema. I'm currently using Apollo, and so my Schema is inside of a Javascript file.

The routine for setting the LSP up is [here](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Language-servers#graphql).

I've placed a `.graphqlrc` file in the root of my project, and it's pointing at a Javascript file which contains my schema.

```
schema: api/src/schema.js
```

The Language Server appears to run briefly and lint this file, but crashes quickly and then gives me the following error:

```
[Info  - 3:47:22 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
8/11/2021, 3:47:22 PM [4] (pid: 43189) graphql-language-service-usage-logs: {"type":"usage","messageType":"initialize"}
8/11/2021, 3:47:22 PM [1] (pid: 43189) graphql-language-service-usage-logs: Error: 
      Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers:
        
          - api/src/schema.js
```

Here's my CoC settings file:

```
// coc-settings.json
{
  "languageserver": {
    "graphql": {
      "command": "graphql-lsp",
      "args": ["server", "-m", "stream"],
      "filetypes": [
        "typescript",
        "typescriptreact",
        "graphql",
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

The schema.js file:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

/**
 * Type Definitions for our Schema using the SDL.
 */
const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
  }

  type Pet {
    id: String!
    createdAt: Int!
    name: String!
    type: String!
    img: String!
  }

  type Query {
    pets: [Pet]!
  }

  type Mutation {
    cool: String!
  }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

Comment: Hi, @Harrison I'm having the same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I didn't! I've since moved onto using nvim's built-in language server rather than CoC, but best of luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `schema.js` is not a valid schema file - it is a program that produces a runtime schema. The `schema` configuration option for `graphql-lsp` should point to either a `schema.gql` file, or a file containing JSON data resulting from an introspection query against a live GraphQL service.